# android sqlite - table data cannot be updated

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, updating

the  table ( i.e. vaccines) structure is :

id- auto increment primary key

dose1_date - string

dose2_date - string

The `DatabaseAccessor` class is as follows. The `initDB()` and `setVaccineDates` methods are called from another activity. But the database is not updated. The logged message is found in the logcat however. The `DatabaseHelper` class is not shown here.

```
public class DatabaseAccessor {

    public static DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = null;
    public static SQLiteDatabase rdb = null;
    public static SQLiteDatabase wdb = null;

    public static synchronized final void initDB(Context context) throws Exception {
        if (myDbHelper == null) {
            myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            rdb = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            wdb = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
    }



    public static void setVaccineDates(String birthDate) throws SQLException{


        try {
            String[] selections = null;
            String qry = null;
            qry = "select * from vaccines  order by id";

            Cursor cursor = wdb.rawQuery(qry, selections);

            Log.d("update  qry===== ", qry);

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int rowID = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("dose1_date","66666");
                values.put("dose2_date","7777");
                wdb.update("vaccines", values, "id=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(rowID)});

                //wdb.close();
            }
            cursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }



    }// end of  method  setVaccineDates

}
```

What to do ?

**Edit** :  If I uncomment the `wdb.close()` line , I see in logcat

'06-09 04:21:05.387: W/System.err(4144): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.cloudsoft.vaccine/databases/vaccines2.db
'

Comment: obviously bcz after closing you are trying to to update again inside while loop..

Comment: Do you know if you're reaching the while loop? Is your table populated?

Comment: @DanielK, I said  the logcat message is visible

Comment: why are you using query and while loop to update table? you can directly use `update` method.

Comment: This one -> `Log.d("update  qry===== ", qry);` is outside of the while loop but you did say that the `wdb.close();` method is getting called if you uncomment it now that I notice.

Comment: @Shvet, actually I modified code I used in my app to make it easy to represent in SO. In my original codebase, the while loop is necessary. Other wise a single `update` without any `where clause` would suffice.

Comment: @DanielK, oh yes the `log` message is out of the loop here. I tested with another `log` message inside the loop and it worked i.e. execution entered into the loop .

Comment: Dont you have `id` already to update it? generally we keep id to do `CURD` operations. It will be easier way to use id because it will be unique .

Comment: @Shvet, what do you mean ? `id` is used in the `where` clause of the  `update` method .

Comment: Try to log the int value that the update function returns and see what you get back. You should get one, since you're updating them one by one.

Comment: @DanielK I got 1. But values are not updated in database.

Comment: The int that it returns is the number of records updated so 1 is correct. What makes you think that the database is not being updated?

Comment: @DanielK, I observe manually with sqliteBrowser.

Comment: Then something else must be happening. Either the table gets cleared later, or you're checking the wrong table with the SQLiteBrowser, or something else. You'll have to provide some more context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114261/discussion-between-istiaque-ahmed-and-daniel-k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a newbie in android it was just a mistake out of ignorance that this situation took place: after `update` operation I tried to find the changes in the database file (i.e. file with `.db` extension sitting inside `assets` folder in Eclipse) through [sqlite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) . But what actually happens is the app running in the device (real one or emulator) has its own database which is created from the `.db` extension  file inside `assets` folder and consequent database operations only affect the app's own database    leaving no touch on the database inside the mentioned folder in Eclipse. And there is the way to watch the  app's very own database in the running device  in Eclipse's  'File Explorer' (in DDMS mode) with the help of [Questoid SQlite Manager](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/)